# Reading Sharepoint Excel data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint

I need to read SharePoint Excel file and get required data. For now what I am doing is to download the Excel file on my local machine and then read it. But I want to get rid of downloading part, instead I want to directly read the Excel file on share point and get my required data.

My current code:

```
public string Get(int CSI_ID)
    {
        const string username = "********";
        const string password = "********";
        string url = @"https://globalfunctionsshare.nam.citi.net/";
        var securedPassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray()) securedPassword.AppendChar(c);
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, "eur");
        var path = @"sites/otdrrm/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=%2Fsites%2Fotdrrm%2FDocuments%2Ftools%2FLegal%20Hold%20Application%20Tracker/Legal%20Hold%20Application%20Tracker%2020210702.xlsx";
        DownloadFile(url, credentials, path);

        DataTable dt = ImportExceltoDatatable(@"C:\Users\mk20317\Legal_Hold_Application_Tracker.xlsx", CSI_ID);
        string Status = dt.Rows[0]["Preservation Status"].ToString();
        return Status;
    }
    private static void DownloadFile(string webUrl, ICredentials credentials, string fileRelativeUrl)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())            
        {
            client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
            //client.Credentials = credentials;
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            client.DownloadFile(new Uri(webUrl + fileRelativeUrl), @"C:\Users\mk20317\Legal_Hold_Application_Tracker.xlsx");                
            //var data = client.DownloadString(webUrl + fileRelativeUrl);
            //JObject table = JObject.Parse(data);
        }
    }

    public DataTable ImportExceltoDatatable(string Filepath, int CSI_ID)
    {
        // string sqlquery= "Select * From [SheetName$] Where YourCondition";
        string sqlquery = "Select [Preservation Status] From [App List$] Where [CSI ID]=" + CSI_ID;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring + "");
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlquery, con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        return dt;
    }
```

Though I am able to achieve my requirement here with this code, but It can be more simpler by not downloading it and directly reading the excel from share point like getting the data into memory stream and then reading it.
Please if anyone can suggest or help with getting data into memory stream and then reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can go on Sarepoint and create a drive (OneDrive) on your computer that is connected to Sharepoint. Then you can simply use this path normaly in your code. :-)
Another method can be to go on SharePoint on get the URL on the file (but I think it will download it also).

Comment: I can't create anything, company's security issue's. also i can't do this because later on this code will run on a windows service call. Basically i am creating an API and my url wil be called from windows service